# How to share android screen WITH root?

Tags: screen-sharing

There are so many ways to share screen with PC wirelessly without root.

I've heard that it's even easier with root.

I want to play games and I want the game to show up on my PC screen too.

How do I accomplish that?

My phone is rooted. So rooting is not an issue'

Answer (score 0):

I am using BBQscreen client and it works fine

https://screen.bbqdroid.org/

Answer (score 0):

Either Use MirroGo (through WiFi and USB) or TeamViewer (through the Internet).
If you have a phone of Honor, Huawei or Asus then you can use their Softwares too.
And One last thing if you use any of these softwares, Rooting will not going to matter.